# Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument in complete.cases program

Tags: r

I am writing an R function that reads a directory full of files and reports the number of completely observed cases in each data file. The function returns a data frame where the first column is the name of the file and the second column is the number of complete cases.

such as,

```
id nobs
1  108
2  345
...
etc
```

Here is the function I wrote:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {

  for(i in 1:332) {
    path<-paste(directory,"/",id,".csv",sep="")
    mydata<-read.csv(path)
    #nobs<-nrow(na.omit(mydata))
    nobs<-sum(complete.cases(mydata))
    i<-i+1
  }

  completedata<-c(id,nobs)
}
```

I execute the function:

```
complete("specdata",id=1:332)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

I also tried the `traceback()` function to debug my code and it gives this output:

```
traceback()
# 4: file(file, "rt") at #6
# 3: read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
#    dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...) at #6
# 2: read.csv(path) at #6
# 1: complete("specdata", id = 1:332)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's hard to tell without a completely reproducible example, but I suspect your problem is this line:

```
path<-paste(directory,"/",id,".csv",sep="")
```

`id` here is a vector, so path becomes a vector of character strings, and when you call `read.csv` you're passing it all the paths at once instead of just one. Try changing the above line to

```
path<-paste(directory,"/",id[i],".csv",sep="")
```

and see if that works.

Answer (score 8):

It seems you have a problem with your file path.
You are passing the full vector id =c(1:332) to the file path name.
If your files are named 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv, etc..
You can change this line:

```
path<-paste(directory,"/",id,".csv",sep="")
```

to

```
path<-paste(directory,"/",i,".csv",sep="")
```

and leave out or rework the id input of your function.

Comment: thanks Nathan for helping me out solving the problem and letting me understand where I made mistake.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using a `for` to read the data in, you can try `sapply`. For example

> `mydata <- sapply(path, read.csv)`.

Since `path` is a vector, `sapply` will iterate the vector and apply `read.csv` to it. Therefore, there will be no need for the `for` loop and your code will be much cleaner.

From there you will have a `matrix` which each of your files and their respective information from which you can extract the observations.

To find the observations, you can do `mydata[2,1][[1]]`. Remember that the rows will be your factors and your columns will be your files.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on the exact problem.. file names in the directory "specdata" are named with 001.csv and 002.csv.... 099.csv all the way to file 332.csv
however, when you are recalling id=1 then your file name becomes 1.csv which does not exist in the directory. 
try using this function to get the path of each id file.

```
filepaths <- function (id){
    allfiles = list.files(getwd())
    file.path(getwd(), allfiles[id])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem in this sentence:

```
Browse[2]> read.csv(list.files(".", "XCMS-annotated-diffreport--.*csv$"), row.names = 1)
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

then, I found there are two different csv files in the same path, like this:

```
Browse[2]> list.files(".", "XCMS-annotated-diffreport--.*csv$")
[1] "XCMS-annotated-diffreport--1-vs-2-Y.csv" "XCMS-annotated-diffreport--1-vs-2.csv"
```

When I deleted one file, it works again.

Answer (score 1):

In my code the problem was that I´ve misstyped the name of the file. And the other file was´t in this directory. So check if all files are where they should be.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I was trying to run a for loop against the data frame and not a vector:

```
  ids <- th[th$nobs > threshold,]
  for(i in ids) {
```

this is what the variable "ids" looks like:

```
     id nobs
2     2 1041
154 154 1095
248 248 1005
```

should have been:

```
  ids <- th[th$nobs > threshold,]
  for(i in ids$id) {
```

Answer (score 0):

change object id to i - because you are in for loop with iteration object i
i.e path<-paste(directory,"/",id,".csv",sep="") 
to 
i.e path<-paste(directory,"/",i,".csv",sep="")