# how do i fix this error related to directory in r?

Tags: r

```
pollutantmean<-function(directory,pollutant,id){
id<-as.numeric(id)
if(grep("specdata",directory)==1){
  directory<-"C:\\Users\\SASIDHAR\\Desktop\\coursera\\specdata\\"
}
if(id<10){
newid<-paste("00",id,sep="")
fileid<-paste(newid,".csv",sep="")
filename<-paste(directory,fileid,sep="")
data<-read.csv(filename)
}
else if(id>=10&id<=99){
newid<-paste("0",id,sep="")
fileid<-paste(newid,".csv",sep="")
filename<-paste(directory,fileid,sep="")
data<-read.csv(filename)


}
else{
fileid<-paste(id,".csv",sep="")
filename<-paste(directory,filename,sep="")
data<-read.csv(filename)
}
if(pollutant=="sulfate"){
mean(data$sulfate,na.rm=TRUE)
}
else if(pollutant=="nitrate"){
mean(data$nitrate,na.rm=TRUE)
}
}
```

i wrote this function in r programming and  i am getting this error
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (id < 10) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
can anyone help me with this plzzz i am using windows 8

Comment: Sth wrong with your filename (`\\C:...`)? And `id` seems to contain more than one value.

Comment: i have tried removing it but i am getting the same error and can i know what do you mean by id seems to contain more than one value it  would be very helpful to me

Comment: First, please expand your code by example data so that it triggers your errors when people copy/paste/run it in their R environment. [Here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html) is how you can do it.

Comment: As lukeA mentioned, `id` seems to be a `vector` instead of a single (atomic/scalar) value. Add `id=as.numeric(id)` at start of the function and comment all file read/data processing and just have `return(filename)` at the end of function, this should return `001.csv` for `id=1`. Unless you get this right, data I/O will be error prone

Comment: I am getting the same error after writing id=as.numeric(id) i have edited the function can you see and tell what is wrong plzz

Comment: As I have said earlier, remove all three `else` blocks, from second `if` block remove `data<-read.csv(filename)` and have your last statement as `return(filename)`, let us know the output of these steps

Comment: A google of your error landed to this page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420936/error-in-filefile-rt-invalid-description-argument-in-complete-cases-pro), is your input `id=1:100` or `id=1`

Comment: i am getting the following output source("pollutantmean.R")
> pollutantmean("specdata",1:5)
[1] "C:\\Users\\SASIDHAR\\Desktop\\coursera\\specdata\\001.csv"
[2] "C:\\Users\\SASIDHAR\\Desktop\\coursera\\specdata\\002.csv"
[3] "C:\\Users\\SASIDHAR\\Desktop\\coursera\\specdata\\003.csv"
[4] "C:\\Users\\SASIDHAR\\Desktop\\coursera\\specdata\\004.csv"
[5] "C:\\Users\\SASIDHAR\\Desktop\\coursera\\specdata\\005.csv"
Warning message:
In if (id < 10) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used