# Reading a text file at a URL into an R data frame

Tags: r

I have a text file with columnar data which I want to read into an R data frame. Here is how the text file looks.

```
            absd  kjehfjef
     kjldnflknkdsnfds lkdld
              kjdkskjdjjsbdjsjs

  jkdkjbfsjbsd
          ajdkjsadasjd
           jksabdkjabdw



   STATE         WEEK  WEEK WEEK    CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM
                 TOTAL DEV  DEV     TOTAL DEV   DEV   DEV   DEV
                       FROM FROM          FROM  FROM  FROM  FROM
                       NORM L YR          NORM  L YR  NORM  L YR
                                                      PRCT  PRCT

 ALABAMA            11   11   11    2137   274   217    15    11
 ARIZONA             0    0    0    2622  -341    45   -12     2
 ARKANSAS            1    1    1    1899    99   275     6    17
 CALIFORNIA          0    0    0    1195   345    -6    41     0
```

The data frame should look like this.

```
   STATE         WEEK  WEEK WEEK    CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM
                 TOTAL DEV  DEV     TOTAL DEV   DEV   DEV   DEV
                       FROM FROM          FROM  FROM  FROM  FROM
                       NORM L YR          NORM  L YR  NORM  L YR
                                                      PRCT  PRCT

 ALABAMA            11   11   11    2137   274   217    15    11
 ARIZONA             0    0    0    2622  -341    45   -12     2
 ARKANSAS            1    1    1    1899    99   275     6    17
 CALIFORNIA          0    0    0    1195   345    -6    41     0
```

I want to ignore the junk at the beginning, and just capture the table into a data frame. One problem is that the column headings stretch over multiple lines.

Can someone help me achieve this?

I tried `a<-read.table(text = <file name>, skip = grep("-34 more junk is here", <file name>))` but I got the error "no lines available in input".

Comment: Use the parameter `skip = 4` in `read.table` to skip four lines

Comment: Can you upload a sample file anywhere to serve as an example?

Comment: Maybe this helps with the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420936/error-in-filefile-rt-invalid-description-argument-in-complete-cases-pro

Comment: Again, can you upload a real sample file anywhere to serve as an example? To make a data frame with space rows and those huge names for columns divided by lines will turn things a little bit more difficult. I want to check on that instead of copying and creating a txt file myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(data.table)
a <- fread(file="junk.txt", skip="ALABAMA")
```

Then either add your own column names manually or, if there are too many, attempt to read them in from the file somehow. Maybe using `read.fwf()` or `scan()`.

---

From the help page of fread:

> skip
>   If 0 (default) start on the first line and from there finds the
>   first row with a consistent number of columns. This automatically
>   avoids irregular header information before the column names row.
>   skip>0 means ignore the first skip rows manually. skip="string"
>   searches for "string" in the file (e.g. a substring of the column
>   names row) and starts on that line (inspired by read.xls in package
>   gdata).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do what you want by using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table). The question, as the other answer points out, is that retrieving the column names is the hard part.

```r
data.table::fread(
  file = <file_name>,
  skip = 1
)

#>            V1 V2 V3 V4   V5   V6  V7  V8 V9
#> 1:    ALABAMA 11 11 11 2137  274 217  15 11
#> 2:    ARIZONA  0  0  0 2622 -341  45 -12  2
#> 3:   ARKANSAS  1  1  1 1899   99 275   6 17
#> 4: CALIFORNIA  0  0  0 1195  345  -6  41  0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can also try `read.delim`, but this is ugly as a data frame object.

```r
read.delim(
  file = <file_name>,
  skip = 6,
  col.names = "v"
)

#>                                                                  v
#> 1     STATE         WEEK  WEEK WEEK    CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM
#> 2                   TOTAL DEV  DEV     TOTAL DEV   DEV   DEV   DEV
#> 3                        FROM FROM          FROM  FROM  FROM  FROM
#> 4                        NORM L YR          NORM  L YR  NORM  L YR
#> 5                                                       PRCT  PRCT
#> 6  ALABAMA            11   11   11    2137   274   217    15    11
#> 7  ARIZONA             0    0    0    2622  -341    45   -12     2
#> 8  ARKANSAS            1    1    1    1899    99   275     6    17
#> 9  CALIFORNIA          0    0    0    1195   345    -6    41     0
```